# Mocking Task<IEnumerable<T>> with NSubstitute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I'm having issues trying to get `NSubstitute` to return an `IEnumerable` interface from a `Task`.

The factory I'm mocking:

```
public interface IWebApiFactory<T> : IDisposable
{
    <T> GetOne(int id);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetMany();
    void SetAuth(string token);
}
```

The test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMutlipleUsersAsViewResult()
{
    var employees = new List<EmployeeDTO>()
    {
        new EmployeeDTO(),
        new EmployeeDTO()
    };

    // Arrange
    var factory = Substitute.For<IWebApiFactory<EmployeeDTO>>();
    factory.GetMany().Returns(Task.FromResult(employees));
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task> to System.Func>>

Is this an issue with me passing a list, as a posed to `IEnumerable` even though `List` is `IEnumerable`?

Edit:

These are the functions within `NSubstitute`

```
public static ConfiguredCall Returns<T>(this T value, Func<CallInfo, T> returnThis, params Func<CallInfo, T>[] returnThese);
public static ConfiguredCall Returns<T>(this T value, T returnThis, params T[] returnThese);
```

Comment: Notice the error. You are trying to convert a `System.Func` to `Task`.  I suspect `Returns` expects a lambda, not a concrete value

Comment: Well I thought this, but I've used it with a single object in a previous test and it works fine.  When I pass the list in, it blows up.

Comment: The overloads expect to find the *same* return type of parameter as the function's. This means that the second overload isn't the best match. Try explicitly casting to `Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO>>` or `Task.FromResult((IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO>)employees)`, or simply declare `IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO> employees= ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the overloads is a good match for the value you passed. The second  signature, `public static ConfiguredCall Returns<T>(this T value, T returnThis, params T[] returnThese);` expect a value of the same type as the function's return type so it isn't the best match.

The simplest way to overcome this is to change the declaration of employees to `IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO>` :

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO> employees = new List<EmployeeDTO>()
{
    new EmployeeDTO(),
    new EmployeeDTO()
};
```

Comment: Yeah that was it, I assumed that it would detect the inheritance from List to IEnumerable without a cast but with T it has to be strongly typed? Thanks!

Comment: The behavior you expected is called [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and is supported on interface types or delegate parameters. That's why it works with IEnumerable<T> but not with an extension method

Comment: To be clear, the problem is not the extension method, but the fact that Task<T> is not covariant in T. Thus Task<List<X>> is not a valid argument type when Task<IEnumerable<X>> is expected.